# Copying data if it does not exist

Tags: mysql

I have a database with many tables. One table has 2 columns of data, with column 1 containing "email address" and column 2 containing "newsletterscubscriber" with a value of 1.

I have another table (final table) with the same columns, which is already populated with data. I want to get the database to read the (final table) then to check the first table for any differences. I then want it to add any differences to the final table with both columns of data. By the way this is actually from an oscommerce database.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `table1`.`col1tbl1`, `table1`.`col2tbl1`, `table2`.`col1tbl2`, `table2`.`col2tbl2` FROM `table1`, `table2` WHERE `col1tbl1` != `col1tbl2` AND `col2tbl1` != `col2tbl2`

table1 = final table
table2 = first table
col1tbl1 = name of first column for table1
col2tlb1 = name of second column for table1
col1tbl2 = name of first column for table2
col2tbl2 = name of second column for table2
```

The SQL above will compare the 2 columns from table1 against the 2 columns from table2. If there is no match, it should display all the records from table1 that did not match up. You can then get that data, save it into an array and use recursive script to INSERT the data into table2.

NOTE: I made up the table because you didn't mention any. Also, I obviously couldn't test it but give it a try.